# Singleton not being unique when using dynamic dll loading

Tags: c#, singleton

I'm facing troubles with a Singleton.

This singleton is called from an application and from a custom dll that is loaded through a different class loader.

It's pretty much like I end up having two different instances of my Singleton class...

My implementation of the Singleton is :

```
protected static SingletonImplementation instance = null;
protected static readonly object padLock = new object();

public static SingletonImplementation Instance
{
  get
  {
    lock (padLock)
    {
      if (instance == null)
      {
        instance = new SingletonImplementation();
      }

      return instance;
    }
  }
}

private SingletonImplementation()
{}
```

The solution A defines the Singleton and uses it. The application A creates another DLL that calls this Singleton and that is dynamically loaded by application A.

My applications is scanning a folder to look for all the dll that can be loaded with the following snippet :

```
string[] l_asDlls = Directory.GetFiles(l_sDirectory, sAssemblySearchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
foreach (string l_sFileName in l_asDlls)
{
    Assembly l_assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + l_sFileName);
    Type[] l_aTypes = l_assembly.GetExportedTypes();

    foreach (Type l_type in l_aTypes)
    {            
           lstRemoteCommandServer.Add((ClassBase)Activator.CreateInstance(l_type, this, l_sRepositoryDirectory));
    }
}
```

Within one of the DLL that have been loaded throught the previous snippet, one of them calls my Singleton and it seems that the Singleton that application A has is a different instance of the Singleton that the DLL has.

How can I manage to correct this mistake/behavior ?

Comment: Is it loaded within same AppDomain?

Comment: "class loader" isn't a normal term in .NET development. It would really help if you could give a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem. Are you using multiple AppDomains? How is the custom DLL loaded? How does it reference your class?

Comment: @JonSkeet the rate you respond to questions on singletons / datetime issues is incredible.

Comment: To best find the AppDomain, is it correct to put "Thread.GetDomain().FriendlyName;" both in my Application and in my DLL to check for differences ?

Comment: I checked my AppDomain both in the Main of my Application and just before the snippet where I'm loading the DLL and it is the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is when you load dynamical assemblies. To load in the same AppDomain, use this way :

```
Assembly l_assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(Environment.CurrentDirectory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + l_sFileName));
```